# Keyboard messed up when using Pycharm as an IDE?

Tags: python, pycharm

Don't get me wrong, Pycharm is an amazing IDE, and with its faults, I've still continued to use it and adapt to its way of working. But its getting pretty tedious not being able to do what I want.

Like in other IDE's, I can CTRL+A to select all the text, somehow it almost always messed up in Pycharm, copying all text will result in what ever the INSERT key does, and deletes my content.

Clicking backspace doesn't delete the highlighted content, instead I have to deliperatly click the delete key, and this isn't exactly wrong, but it doesn't fit in with other IDE's.

I noticed when switching from Pycharm to another IDE, I was doing what I did in Pycharm and it just felt unnatural, is there a way to make Pycharm work like other IDE's?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into `File->Settings` and select `Keymap`, there is a drop-down menu where you can select the emulation that you prefer including `Emacs`, `Netbeans`, and `Visual Studio`

Comment: I've just set it to Visual Studio and I still don't have access to the CTRL + A shortcut, or any of the others.

Comment: If you look at `Editor Actions` on the same page, you can set you own keyboard shortcuts for things like `Select Line at Carat`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in another forum:
"Please disable IdeaVim plugin on the File | Settings | Plugins tab."

Worked for me.